# How to echo site url if not on index.php while using anchor based nav

Tags: navigation, frontpage, home-url

I've been attempting to hack together a single page Wordpress theme. So far I've had success in displaying the page loop for content and nav, and I've used JQuery page-scroll to animate the navigation between pages successfully.

However the page-scroll only works if the `href` target is a standalone `#anchor`, not a full url like `mysite.com#anchor`. This is fine until I incorporated additional pages outside of the single page and tried to navigate back using the #anchors without the full url.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

<?php query_posts('post_type=page'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<li class="page-scroll nav-item">

<a class="nav-link" href="<?php if (is_page( 2188 ) ): echo esc_url( home_url('') ); 
endif;?>#<?php global $post; echo $post->post_name; ?>">

<?php the_title(); ?>

</a>

</li>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<li class="page-scroll nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('') ); ?>/blog">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I need is the `echo esc_url( home_url('') );` to only function on pages other than the `index.php`.

I think I might be mixing the syntax for inside and outside of the loop but I can't seem to find the correct combination of queries!

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean `index.php` or 'front page'? If latter, use conditional [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/).

Comment: I've tried `is_front_page()` targeting ID, slug and title and `is_page_template()` with no affect. Currently `index.php` is being called up as the front page.

Comment: `is_front_page()` does not need any parameters: `if( is_front_page() ) { $do_your_stuff_here = true; } else { $do_your_stuff_here = false }`

Comment: Apologies, a typo there, I meant I've tried `is_front_page()`, and targeting ID, slug and title with `is_page` and I've tried `is_page_tenplate()`.

Comment: Front Page is what you see when you go to the main page of your site.  When you are on the Front Page, `is_front_page()` returns `true`. It does not depend on the file you are using to render it. What depends on file is where you put the code for the Front Page. Make sure you use `index.php` as the template for the Front Page. I'm not sure because your example must work with `is_front_page()` without fail.

  Also, I'm not sure you need `global $post;`